# To what extent are the radius ratio rules valid for predicting the crystal structure of an ionic compound?

Tags: crystal-structure, ionic-compounds, solid-state-chemistry

The ionic radii of $\ce{Ba^2+}$ and $\ce{O^2-}$ in barium oxide are $\pu{135pm}$ and $\pu{140pm}$, respectively. The ratio of the radius of $\ce{Ba^2+}$ to $\ce{O^2-}$ is approximately $0.964$.

According to the [radius ratio rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cation-anion_radius_ratio) the solid barium oxide should crystallise in a body-centered cubic type structure (like $\ce{CsCl}$).

[image: Radius Ratio]

But [evidently](https://www.webelements.com/compounds/barium/barium_oxide.html) the prototype structure is $\ce{NaCl}$ type.

What is the reason for this anomaly from general trend?

EDIT: I found that every alkaline earth metal oxides (Of the type $\ce{M_{alk.e}O}$) possesses rock salt (halite) structure but only $\ce{MgO}$ obeys the radius ratio rule (it has a radius ratio of about $0.64$ which is well between $0.414$ and $0.732$).

Certainly as we are going down the group the cationic radius is going to increase and so is the radius ratio.

Comment: The mentioned trend is but a crude generalization.

Comment: Please elaborate....

Comment: What's to elaborate? Tall guys play basketball, short guys play football; that's an **empirical correlation**. It is mostly true, but exceptions both ways are plenty. On the other hand, $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$; that's a **law**. Can it be broken? Not a chance. Well, your trend is not a law.

Comment: Sir, Any reasons for this "exception"?

Comment: The reason is basically that the crystal structure was measured and found to be the NaCl structure. Now good luck finding a reason.

Comment: But I thought exceptions do have reasons.

Comment: @Serotonin *Everything* has a reason; it's just that you'll have to wait till someone figures out *what* the reason is... ;)